# Change http to https in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, htaccess, https, http-request

getting some error in the console

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.xxxxx.com/bedroom/beds/beds-
without-storage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure 
image 'http://www.xxxxx.com/skin/frontend/rwd/yagotimber/images/home-
look.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
beds-without-storage:358 Mixed Content: The page at 
'https://www.xxxxx.com/bedroom/beds/beds-without-storage' was loaded 
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 
'http://www.xxxxx.com/skin/frontend/rwd/yagotimber/images/home-
look2.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

secure url not show ??
how to fix it. any one help me.

Comment: Quick way is change base secure and un secure url to https

Comment: <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that the URL is hardcoded. This error is raised when an unsecure (HTTP) URL is requested somewhere on the page, while the page itself is secure (HTTPS). Try to look for any hardcoded HTTP URL's on the source code or error console and fix those, the error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

My hosting service recommended this site: https://www.whynopadlock.com/ You can check individual pages for insecure content.